# Samurai multi-classing into paladin but with low CHA

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class

I'll try to make this short. I am a level 12 Samurai at the moment and I wish to multiclass into paladin, but the sad part is I have a modifier of 0 in Charisma, so that's out the door unless you guys see something I can do with it. I wish to turn into a Sam/pal story purpose.

My stats are as follows

Str -18
Dex-20
Con- 14
int- 10
wis - 9 (lol)
Char- 10

TL;DR I want to be a pally, but my CHA is low... Can it be done?

Comment: We do one question at a time so I removed the "flash step" part of this question as secondary. You can ask a second question about how to achieve that kind of effect.

Comment: ...okay...? ....seem to get my answer just fine from my original way, but thanks?

Answer (score 3):

**Investigate Archetypes that downplay the CHA requirement.**

I would recommend [The Warrior of The Holy Light](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/warrior-of-the-holy-light), which gives up spell casting for a very powerful aura-buff.

In addition to a low CHA, you also have a low INT and WIS, so any spell casting class becomes less effective.

The good porting flavor options I know involve spells like [Bladed Dash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bladed-dash), or class features that involve heavy investment in spell casting classes like a [Travel Domain Cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/travel-domain).

It sounds to me like a Paladin is still a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is nothing stopping you from multi-classing to a pally, even with low Charisma. I'm assuming you are Lawful Good, as that IS a hard requirement.

The majority of Paladin abilities are either charisma independent (eg. Aura of courage) or still offer decent utility with low charisma (eg. Smite Evil, Lay on hands). Yes, you would be better with high charisma, and you won't be able to cast any spells, but if all you want is the story benefit it would still work.

Note 1: Picking up a [Headband of Alluring Charisma +4](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-alluring-charisma) will allow you to cast all your spells and give you lots of bonuses, and isn't prohibitively expensive (16,000gp)

Note 2: Multi-classing in general in Pathfinder tends to be weaker overall than a pure class progression. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**You may consider multi-classing into Inquisitor instead.**

1. Thematically, [Inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) is close to Paladin.
2. If you choose the [Travel](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/travel-domain) domain for your inquisitor, you have enough
   levels left to get "Dimensional Hop".

> Dimensional Hop (Sp): At 8th level, you can teleport up to 10 feet per
>   cleric level per day as a move action.

3. CHA is mostly a dump stat for Inquisitor as well.

Comment: But wisdom isn't, and he only has a 9.

Comment: @GreySage, Yes, the option is not 'better' than the paladin, with the given limitations it's roughly the same. But being a Travel domain Inquisitor fulfills a secondary requirement, at least.